# form submitting to iframe when the iframe is inside that form

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I just find out an interesting thing about a `form` submitting to an `iframe` when the `iframe` is defined inside the `form`.

```
<form id="form_role">
   <iframe id="iframe_role" name="iframe_role">
   </iframe>
</form>
```

I submit `form_role` to `iframe_role`:

```
document.getElementById("form_role").method = "post";
document.getElementById("form_role").action = "ABC.jsp";
document.getElementById("form_role").target = "iframe_role";
document.getElementById("form_role").submit();
```

In Chrome, `ABC.jsp` loads but without the `iframe`; i.e. I lose the `iframe`.

In IE & Opera, `ABC.jsp` loads in the `iframe`.

What is the standard in this case? Who is right as per specs: Chrome or IE/Opera?

If I put the iframe out of form:

```
<iframe id="iframe_role" name="iframe_role">
</iframe>
<form id="form_role">
</form>
```

then `ABC.jsp` loads in the `iframe` in Chrome, IE and Opera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a little bit ugly to have an `iframe` in a `form`. I think that there does not exist something like a standard in this case. You have answered your question by yourself:

```
<iframe id="iframe_role" name="iframe_role">
</iframe>
<form id="form_role">
</form>
```

is plain **HTML**.